Flutter Android - HTTP plugin error OS Error: Machine is not on the network, errno = 64
I'm using Flutter for Android, and I'm attempting to make an HTTP call on a restricted network (no internet connection) after switching the Wi-Fi using the WifiIOT plugin in Flutter. I've successfully connected to an IoT device's Wi-Fi.
However, when I try to make a call to an IP address on this network, I receive the following error: "OS Error: Machine is not on the network, errno = 64."
Same with Dio plugin.
Here the sample code :
var result = await dio.get("http://192.168.33.1/rpc/Webhook.ListSupported");
Has anyone encountered this error before? And if so, have you found a solution?
Thanks!
Interestingly, when I connect my PC to this network and make the same call to the URL, I receive the correct response.

Did you enable clear text traffic to be able to use http protocol?

Try a browser on your Android device too.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Yes, android:usesCleartextTraffic is set to "true".

Chrome on Android returns the error "ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED," but on my PC, I can access the URL without any issues. Is there anything I can do to access the IP even if there is no internet connection on this network?

I've updated the question with the sample code of my request, thx

I am experiencing a similar issue as described in this thread while working on a Flutter project for Android. I am trying to establish a WebSocket connection to an ESP32 on a local network managed by the device itself (i.e., no internet access). I was unable to establish a Websocket connection, so I additionnaly used WiFiForIoTPlugin.forceWifiUsage(true); which initially seemed to resolve the connection issue. However, intermittently, I receive the exact same error as mentioned above.
